# Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.security.PublicKey.getFormat()' on a null object reference

Tags: crash

Need some helps!!!

My app crashes on Android 5.0 Lollipop with the following exception. It works on previous versions.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.security.PublicKey.getFormat()' on a null object reference
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.fromPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:108)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSignature.engineInitVerify(OpenSSLSignature.java:170)
at java.security.Signature$SignatureImpl.engineInitVerify(Signature.java:684)
at java.security.Signature.initVerify(Signature.java:268)
at com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator.com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback getCallback()(Unknown Source) 
void verify(java.security.PublicKey,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
void handleResponse(com.android.vending.licensing.Policy$LicenseResponse,com.android.vending.licensing.ResponseData)
void handleApplicationError(com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback$ApplicationErrorCode)
at com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker$ResultListener$2.void run()(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can give me some idea how to troubleshoot it.

Regards,
Cowcow

Answer (score -2):

Add:

```
java.security.Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

before using   PdfPKCS7 signatureProperties = af.verifySignature(signature);



   FileInputStream is;

                is = new FileInputStream(input);

                java.security.Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);


               //org.spongycastle.cms.CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = new CmsSignedData(stream);



                try


                {

                    PdfReader PDFReader = new PdfReader(is);

                AcroFields af = PDFReader.getAcroFields();

                ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();

                for(Iterator<String> i = names.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

                    String signature = i.next();

                    //obtain information about the signature
                    PdfPKCS7 signatureProperties = af.verifySignature(signature);
                    infoText.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + signatureProperties.getDigestAlgorithmOid());
```